# Some computation about Laplace operator

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $$y=\frac{x}{|x|^2}$$  in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $u(x)$ be a smooth function, and let $$v(y)=|x|^{n-2}u(x)$$

Then we have $$\Delta_y v(y)=|x|^{n+2}\Delta_x u(x)$$

How to prove this?

I know some straightforward calculation would work, but I want to see it more directly.(Or maybe there is some easier way to compute this?)

Answer (score 1):

$x = \frac{y}{|y|^2} \Rightarrow |x|^2 = \frac{1}{|y|^2}$. Now
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} 
&= 
\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{\partial x_k}{\partial y_j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\\
&= 
\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{\delta_{jk} |y|^2 - 2 y_j y_k}{|y|^4} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\\
&= 
\frac{1}{|y|^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} - \frac{2 y_j}{|y|^4} \sum_{k=1}^n y_k \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k},
\end{align*}
hence
$$
\nabla_y =
\frac{1}{|y|^2} \nabla_x - \frac{2 y}{|y|^4} y \cdot \nabla_x 
$$
and finally
\begin{align*}
\Delta_y
&=
\nabla_y \cdot \nabla_y\\
&=
\frac{1}{|y|^4} \nabla_x \cdot \nabla_x
- \frac{4}{|y|^6} (y \cdot \nabla_x)^2
+ \frac{4}{|y|^6} (y \cdot \nabla_x)^2\\
&=
|x|^4 \Delta_x
\end{align*}

Comment: It seems you are wrong.